# Is AOP a type of decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, aop, decorator

I got asked this question in a interview. I clearly know what a decorator pattern is and how it can be used. But I was not able to think through this question in the interview.

This is the actual question asked.

> Is AOP a variation of decorator pattern ? How does the AOP implementation vary from trademark decorator pattern ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would say [AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is NOT a pattern by itself (and thus not a type of decorator pattern from my POV)... its implementation can be done via one or more patterns (including the use of [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern))... AOP is a [programming paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) IMHO - other paradigms are for example OOP, functional programming or procedural programming...

Comment: AOP implementations use mainly a mix of Proxy and Decorator.

Comment: The semantics of AOP operates at the language level: adding keywords, changing control flows etc.; whereas Decorator operates entirely within the semantics of OOP (just overriding virtual methods). This makes Decorator a pattern, while AOP would have qualified as a "language extension".

Comment: @rwong That depends on what language it's being implemented in, e.g., for AspectJ, yes. For more dynamic languages it can just be a library.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Yahia in general. Note that while aspects add and possibly modify existing functionality, they are usually applied to whole methods or classes, not single instances.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the "whole method/class versus single instance" point :-)

Answer (score 7):

I would say in a way, yes, AOP is an implementation of the decorator pattern.

For me the biggest differences would be in how it's implemented, and how it's applied.

Traditional decorators are usually objects that either composite the object being decorated explicitly, or are enabled by an extension point of the underlying object.

AOP is generally specified in a more "declarative" manner--traditional decorators are generally part of the mainline code (as opposed to, say, annotations, config files, or some form of configured byte code manipulation system).

Traditional decorators are generally only applicable to specific classes or interfaces, and are generally applied at the instance level. AOP (in general) can wrap functionality around essentially arbitrary code at the "ground level"--the behavior will extend to *all* instances of whatever the aspect is applied to. This is what allows it to satisfy its claim of "cross-cutting functionality": it's not necessarily limited to as narrow a scope as decorators are.

This depends on the underlying language, however--some are more flexible than others. The above applies more to "static" languages (e.g., Java) and not so much to a language like Ruby, where what looks like a traditional decorator could be applied to a single instance, or become part of the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, dependency injection frameworks that support interception for cross-cutting concerns basically apply the decorator pattern under the hood. Frameworks which weave aspects into the intermediate language (as in .Net MSIL) don't rely on interfaces or inheritance, unlike the decorator pattern.